# Regex for double only input in textfield

Tags: regex, javafx, double

I know it is frequent question, but i did some research and can't find answer.In my javafx project i have textfileds, where user can only type double (currency value). 
Program checks input by code:

```
sumText.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d{0,7}([\\.]\\d{0,2})?")) {
                sumText.setText(oldValue);
            }
        }
    });
```

Its all working great, but now i need to modify regex, so it allows input negative numbers also. How can i modify regex to do that? All standart "regex for all doubles" not working, because it moment of input it can be "-" and "". Adding ^[\+\-] in begin of expression doesn't help also.

Comment: Add `-?` at the start.

Comment: oh, soo simple, i feel stupid right now... thank you @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You should look into [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html).